# Error "must declare scalar variable" when using a in memory table in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am converting a `varchar` to `xml` and putting it into a in memory table so that I can query it, but I keep getting an error

> Must declare the scalar variable

This is my code:

```
Declare @templatexml table (CurrentTemplateXml XML Not Null)

insert into @templatexml(CurrentTemplateXml)
    select 
        convert(xml, convert(nvarchar(max), O.CurrentTemplateXml))
    From 
        BMObject O 


select * 
from 
    (select 
         T.C.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(max)') as name
     from 
         @templatexml.nodes('(ObjectTemplate/Sections/Section)') as T(C)
    ) as temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared table variable `@templatexml`, but you use it like variable of `xml` type.

It seems that in place of

```
select T.C.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(max)') as name
from @templatexml.nodes('(ObjectTemplate/Sections/Section)') as T(C)
```

you want to use

```
select T.C.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(max)') as name
from @templatexml tx
    cross apply tx.CurrentTemplateXml.nodes('(ObjectTemplate/Sections/Section)') as T(C)
```